# what is the different between double and int16 while using audioplayer in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio-player

I have a vector keeps audio data, with frequency of 48k. The data consist of integers, max value is about 4k. Vector type is **<1x768000 double>** . When I build my player with this vector type just like below:

```
a1 = audioplayer(A,48000);
a1.play();
```

resultant audio is much noisy, like SNR value smaller than 1(which means I the amount of noise is higher than the thing that I want to hear).

However when I cast the data to int16 and play the sound just like below:

```
a2 = audioplayer(int16(A),48000);
a2.play();
```

resultant audio is very smooth and SNR is like 7-8 or something(not measured or calculated, the noise is barely detectable, but there is forsure.)

So here is my question again: what is the different between double and int16 while using audioplayer in matlab?

PS: *I can provide **A** if you wish.*

PS2: ***A*** contains speech and a bit noise(not a special type, it is probably because of bad microphone etc.) as usual.

Comment: could be because of big values of A? Floating point numbers can not represent all the numbers, and the higher the value the bigger the step between a representable number and it next. Don't know, just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on the API. According to [API for audioplayer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioplayer.html) accepts values between -1 and 1 when input is in double type. When I first used it in double type, it did not scale values properly between -1 and 1, just tries to play them. Instead of just using original values of A, scaling before playing fixes the issue.

```
a3 = audioplayer(A/max(abs(A)),48000);
a3.play();
```

scales the vector properly. It is as good as

```
a2 = audioplayer(int16(A),48000);
a2.play();
```